# variadic-functions to a dynamic array?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to allocate the strings from the input into an array. To create a dynamic memory allocation I need the character length from each word from the input. But how can I do this in this case with a variadic-function.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int size_of_input, ...) //From the input. For example foo(3, "Foo", "Bar", "Something")
{
   int i;
   va_list va_data;

   char **input = malloc(values * sizeof(char*)) //This of course won't work. Is there a good alternative ? I don't wanna use a static array.

   for (i = 0; i < size_of_input; i++)
   {
       input[i] = va_arg(va_data, char*); //The type of the input.
   }
  va_end(va_data);

  /*
     ...
     Continue with the array.
  */

  free(input);
  return;
}
```

Comment: But you *do* have the number of strings passed, isn't it `size_of_input`, the very first argument to the function? Can't you use that when allocating memory for `input`?

Comment: No, because if I would have 5 arguments, it would allocate 5 chars long, but not the actual size.

Comment: What *is* the "actual size"? If it's not the value in `size_of_input` you simply can't know and there's no way of knowing the exact number of strings passed. The value in `size_of_input` is the *only* way you currently have of knowing the number of arguments. If the caller passes more than that, or worse *less* than that, it's not your or your functions problem but the callers problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
void foo(int size_of_input, ...)
{
    int i;
    va_list va_data;

    char **input = malloc(size_of_input * sizeof(char*));
    if(input == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    va_start(va_data, size_of_input);
    for (i = 0; i < size_of_input; i++)
    {
        input[i] = strdup(va_arg(va_data, char*));
    }
    va_end(va_data);

    /* ... Continue with the array. */

    for (i = 0; i < size_of_input; i++)
    {
        free(input[i]);
    }
    free(input);
}
```

`strdup` isn't quite standard, but most systems have it, declared in `<string.h>`.  If you don't have it, it's simple to write:

```
char *mystrdup(char *str)
{
    char *ret = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);        /* +1 for \0 */
    if(ret == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(ret, str);
    return ret;
}
```

Note that in all of this we're performing N+1 allocations: N for the strings, and 1 for the array of pointers pointing to them.  Therefore we have to perform N+1 frees when we're done.  Perhaps you wanted to perform exactly 1 allocation (and 1 free).  That's doable, but trickier.

---

Addendum: Depending on what you're doing in the "continue with the array" part, you might not need to reallocate the strings at all.  For the duration of function `foo()`, before it returns, all the passed strings remain valid, so you actually could do

```
input[i] = va_arg(va_data, char *);
```

just as you had first written.  (In that case, of course, you wouldn't need or want my `for (i = 0; i < size_of_input; i++) free(input[i]);` loop at the end.)